# Display mutliple lists in a list box

Tags: c#, list, class, listbox, multiple-inheritance

I am using c# Visual Basic 2017 and I am trying to create a listbox which will display 3 different lists together at the same time and want to know if this is possible. The listbox can currently display each list on it's own through the use of the ".datasource =" function. Each list is of type class, these classes are all different however there is one superclass and 2 subclasses.

This is how i have named and filled the lists in my form:

```
public partial class formHome : Form
{
    // Naming and creating my lists at class level so other classes such as buttons can access the lists
    List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
    List<Hospitality> hosps = new List<Hospitality>();
    List<Conference> confs = new List<Conference>();



    public formHome()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Fill Event list
        events.Add(new Event(1, new DateTime(2017, 12, 21), new DateTime(2017, 12, 22), "National Glass Centre", 20, 7.50, "Dynamo Kick off Meeting, Dec 2017"));
        events.Add(new Event(2, new DateTime(2017, 12, 15), new DateTime(2017, 12, 16), "Winter Gardens Museum", 30, 2.99, "Nature Preservation Meeting"));
        events.Add(new Event(3, new DateTime(2018, 1, 5), new DateTime(2018, 1, 6), "Theatre Royal", 120, 5.00, "Traditional Irish Dancing"));

        // Fill Hospitality list
        hosps.Add(new Hospitality(4, new DateTime(2017, 12, 21), new DateTime(2017, 12, 22), "Stadium of Light", 100, 25.00, "SAFC Charity Auction", false));
        hosps.Add(new Hospitality(5, new DateTime(2017, 11, 19), new DateTime(2017, 11, 20), "Empire Cinema", 200, 7.50, "School Cinema Day", true));

        // Fill Conference list
        confs.Add(new Conference(6, new DateTime(2017, 11, 15), new DateTime(2017, 11, 16), "Marriot Hotel", 400, 5.00, "NHS Christmas Night Out", false, false));
        confs.Add(new Conference(7, new DateTime(2017, 12, 31), new DateTime(2018, 1, 1), "Hilton Hotel", 500, 10.00, "Police New Years Eve Meeting", true, true));
        confs.Add(new Conference(8, new DateTime(2018, 2, 4), new DateTime(2018, 2, 5), "Stadiun of Light", 1000, 7.50, "Duke of Edinburgh Award", true, true));
        confs.Add(new Conference(9, new DateTime(2018, 3, 5), new DateTime(2018, 3, 6), "St.Peters Campus", 500, 0, "Results Day", false, true));

    }
```

Event is a superclass of both Hospitality and Conference, Hospitality and Conference and both subclasses of Event.

Currently using this method to display one list at a time in my list box:

```
private void btnSeenormal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear list box before entering information
        liDisplay.DataSource = null;

        // Adding list items of type Event to list box
        liDisplay.DataSource = events;
    }
```

How can I display all 3 at the same time, or how can I merge the 3 lists into one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of doing `hosps.Add` and `confs.Add` you should do `events.Add`.

Comment: I don't see the reason to do this, as then I would only have 1 list and I have been tasked with displaying the information back to the user by type. So there are 4 buttons on the form which give the user the option to display normal events, hospitality events, and conference events, and all events together.

Comment: You can still maintain 3 lists and with hospitality and conference objects added to both events list and their respective lists.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example of how to do that, I'm fairly new to coding so don't know how i would go about it.

Comment: Can You share the class definitions of event, hospitality and conference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your situation with [Polymophism](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson09) in mind. Given that

1. Hospitality IS-A Event
2. Conference IS-A Event

You could combine all 3 lists into one list of Events by doing

```
events.AddRange(hosps);
events.AddRange(confs);
```

or if you want to keep the current events list separate and combine them in another variable:

```
List<Event> allEvents = new List<Event>();
allEvents.AddRange(events)
allEvents.AddRange(hosps);
allEvents.AddRange(confs);
```

ensuring that you have Added items to the events, hosps and confs variables before calling AddRange against allEvents.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified it a bit for your example with the following two classes:

```
public class Students
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
public class Teachers
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TeacherId { get; set;}
}
```

And then you didn't clarify what you want to show, but for a simple *Just show some values* you can select class properties and add them to either a new list first, or directly to the control like so:

```
        List<Students> students = new List<Students>()
        {
            new Students() {Name = "Ray", Year = "2017"},
            new Students() { Name = "Carla", Year = "2019" }
        };

        List<Teachers> teachers = new List<Teachers>()
        {
            new Teachers() {Name = "Mr. Smith", TeacherId = 151},
            new Teachers() {Name = "Mrs. Barbara", TeacherId = 901}
        };

        listBox1.Items.AddRange(teachers.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray());
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(students.Select(s => s.Name).ToArray());
```

It's not the most performant way to do it however, but would work fine for small datasets.

Comment: Thank you loads for the help, finally finished the program, all i needed to know was how to add multiple lists using that array function. added the 3 lists and it works sound. thanks again guys.

Comment: @OliverAllen That's great! Glad we can help. Just please remember to upvote answers that helped you AND accept an answer to help future searchers